# Dealing with tuples for json.loads

Tags: python

I have a string that contains a dictionary, and inside there's a field that has values that are list of tuples. When I try to load the string into json, it fails.

The format looks like

```
{'info_scetion': {'category1': [('response 1', '{"tag1":"str1", "tag2":"str2"}')]}}
```

This is one of the special inputs I receive, and it is the only one that contains a list of tuple. I do not generate the input, so I cannot change the format. Because JSON cannot parse this string directly, I was thinking about trying to identify the tuple inside the string and pick it out. For the rest, the code should be able to process.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to do it. I tried forming a regex that uses `(` and `)` in some forms like `(.*?)` to get the first incidence, but I cannot guarantee there wouldn't be any `)` in the actual tuple.

If I go with this direction, how do I correctly identify the tuple?

If there's another way to do it, what is it?

EDIT: adding the `}` at the end

Comment: You have another problem in your string: JSON requires that double quotes are used for string, not single quotes.

Comment: Your json is malformed. `}` is missing in the end.

Comment: This is the input I got as a string. I don't create that json. All the quotations are exactly what they are....except the closing }. Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You 'JSON' is not really a JSON: it is a Python data structure, so parse it as such with the AST module:

```
s = "{'info_scetion': {'category1': [('response 1', '{\"tag1\":\"str1\", \"tag2\":\"str2\"}')]}}"
result = ast.literal_eval(s)
result
#{'info_scetion': {'category1': \
#                 [('response 1', '{"tag1":"str1", "tag2":"str2"}')]}}
```

Once it is imported into Python, you can manipulate it in any way you like. For example, you can "flatten" the list of tuple:

```
result['info_scetion']['category1'] = list(result['info_scetion']['category1'][0])
#{'info_scetion': {'category1': ['response 1', '{"tag1":"str1", "tag2":"str2"}']}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your json is malformed, it is missing a `}` at the end.

I tested things with this code and things seem to be fine.

```
data = {'info_scetion': {'category1': [('response 1', '{"tag1":"str1", "tag2":"str2"}')]}}

print data['info_scetion']['category1'][0][0]
# output >> response 1

print json.loads(data['info_scetion']['category1'][0][1])['tag1']
# output >> str1
```

Comment: Your `data` is not a string.

Comment: @DYZ : look at the second example (line#6), that is all he needs to read a dictionary from a string input (hence the 2 examples)

Comment: But you `data` is still not a string, and in the OP it is a string. The problem is how to comvert that string to a Python data structure.

Comment: I doubt that. His question says `I have a string that contains a dictionary` which is `'{"tag1":"str1", "tag2":"str2"}'` in the `data dictionary`. This read is failing because he has a  missing `}`.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the whole first sentence of the OP, not just the first half of it.

Comment: @sudhishkr yea @DYZ is correct here. sorry for the misunderstanding. Converting is the problem. Once I get it into a dict, I know what I can do. But you're right, my original example was missing a `}`